# TimerTrigger Not Acting Reliably

Tags: azure-webjobssdk

Here's the output from the WebJobs dashboard.

```
[02/25/2016 15:17:43 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] WebJob is still running
[02/25/2016 15:30:00 > 73b01b: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.CleanupReports' - Reason: 'Timer fired at 2016-02-25T09:30:00.0176405-06:00'
[02/25/2016 15:30:05 > 73b01b: INFO] Executed: 'Functions.CleanupReports' (Succeeded)
[02/25/2016 15:45:00 > 73b01b: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.CleanupReports' - Reason: 'Timer fired at 2016-02-25T09:45:00.0207587-06:00'
[02/25/2016 15:45:06 > 73b01b: INFO] Executed: 'Functions.CleanupReports' (Succeeded)
[02/25/2016 16:00:00 > 73b01b: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.CleanupReports' - Reason: 'Timer fired at 2016-02-25T10:00:00.0145779-06:00'
[02/25/2016 16:00:05 > 73b01b: INFO] Executed: 'Functions.CleanupReports' (Succeeded)
[02/25/2016 16:15:00 > 73b01b: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.CleanupReports' - Reason: 'Timer fired at 2016-02-25T10:15:00.0159180-06:00'
[02/25/2016 16:15:05 > 73b01b: INFO] Executed: 'Functions.CleanupReports' (Succeeded)
[02/25/2016 16:20:10 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[02/25/2016 16:20:13 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[02/25/2016 16:20:13 > 73b01b: INFO] Job host stopped
[02/25/2016 16:20:13 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
[02/25/2016 16:20:13 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[02/25/2016 16:21:12 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[02/25/2016 16:21:36 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] Run script 'ScheduledJobs.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[02/25/2016 16:21:36 > 73b01b: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[02/25/2016 16:21:49 > 73b01b: INFO] Found the following functions:
[02/25/2016 16:21:49 > 73b01b: INFO] ScheduledJob.Functions.CleanupReports
[02/25/2016 16:21:49 > 73b01b: INFO] ScheduledJob.Functions.GenerateDailyReports
[02/25/2016 16:21:50 > 73b01b: INFO] ScheduledJob.Functions.GenerateStatusReport
[02/25/2016 16:21:50 > 73b01b: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.CleanupReports' - Reason: 'Timer fired at 2016-02-25T10:21:50.2837475-06:00'
[02/25/2016 16:21:51 > 73b01b: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.GenerateStatusReport' - Reason: 'Timer fired at 2016-02-25T10:21:50.3462787-06:00'
[02/25/2016 16:21:51 > 73b01b: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.GenerateDailyReports' - Reason: 'Timer fired at 2016-02-25T10:21:50.6119032-06:00'
```

Method signatures:

```
// Run every 15 minutes on the 15 minute interval (e.g. 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00)
public static async Task CleanupReports([TimerTrigger("0 0/15 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)

// Run at 00:00 AM local time, every day
public static async Task GenerateDailyReports([TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)

// Run at 06:00 local time, every day
public static void GenerateStatusReport([TimerTrigger("0 0 6 * * *", RunOnStartup = false)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
```

Nuget Package Versions:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Exceptionless" version="3.3.1575" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Exceptionless.Portable" version="3.3.1575" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow" version="4.5.24" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" version="1.0.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ncrontab" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Polly-Signed" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.ServiceBus" version="3.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Why did those functions get re-ran a few minutes ago? The RunOnStartup is clearly false. It's like it didn't get honored by the system.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to set RunOnStartup to false explicitly since false is the default. Does this issue happen reliably? Anything special about your setup (staging slots, scaled out instances, etc.)? You might also set config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel to Verbose. In cases where we execute on startup because we think we're behind schedule, we write some Verbose logs. Those would tell if that is happening. Another option - we have a prerelease build up now on myget that has some TimerTrigger bug fixes - you could try that if you wish.

Comment: @mathewc Nope, nothing special. It hasn't happened again, so I'm not real concerned about it. I'll look into the verbose logging.